# nothing is saved after updating form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a Candidat models and Experience_Pro models as shown below with fk relation between them .
i can register or login a candidat(user) and a profil page with firstname and lastname of that candidat shown, and a form for Experience_Pro for the user to add if he does have one .
but when i enter all the info in the Experience_Pro form and click update nothing is added to candidat

I don't know what i am missing but the form is showing with no errors and even after i update the profile no errors but nothing is saved to candidat

models.py

```
class Candidat(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience_Pro = models.ForeignKey('Experience_Pro' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, 
                                         null=True,default='')

class Experience_Pro(models.Model):
    annee_debut = models.IntegerField()
    annee_fin = models.IntegerField()
    description_exp_pro = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateCandidat(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model=Candidat
       fields=['experience_Pro']

class CreateExperience_Pro(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Experience_Pro
        fields='__all__'
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profil(request):
   exp_form = CreateExperience_Pro()
   c_form = UpdateCandidat()
   if exp_form.is_valid():
       exp = exp_form.save()
       candidat = c_form.save(commit=False)
       candidat.save(experience_Pro=exp)
       return redirect('profil')
   context={
      'exp_form':exp_form
   }
   return render(request ,'candidats/profil.html',context)
```

profil.html

```
<h1>Profil Candidat</h1>
    <p>Prenom: {{ user.first_name }}</p>
    <p>Nom: {{ user.last_name }}</p>
    <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>

    <form method="POST" action="">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {% comment %} {{ c_form }} {% endcomment %}
       {{ exp_form }}
       <input type="submit"  value="Update">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some update:

```
@login_required
def profil(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        exp_form = CreateExperience_Pro(request.POST)
        c_form = UpdateCandidat(request.POST)
        if exp_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
            exp = exp_form.save()
            candidat = c_form.save()
            return redirect('profil')
        else:
            context = {
                'exp_form': exp_form,
                'c_form': c_form,
            }
            return render(request, 'candidats/profil.html', context)
    else:
        exp_form = CreateExperience_Pro()
        c_form = UpdateCandidat()
        context = {'exp_form': exp_form, 'c_form': c_form}
        return render(request, 'candidats/profil.html', context)
```

Comment: i get this error now "save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'experience_Pro'" akhti Houda

Comment: Sorry I copied it from your code, didn't pay attention. I updated it

Comment: let me know if you have any mochkil

Comment: it's not working as i intended , but it's working . thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "as i intended"! don't hesitate if you have any problem I'm here to help you ?

Comment: it's saving Experience_Pro alone with no relation to candidat

Comment: are you sure that you don't use commit=False for c_form.save()